# REGEX: Storing expressions in XML

Tags: regex, xml

I have a set of regular expressions that are being stored in a XML file. However, for an expression that contains `&&` the `.XML` file fails validation.

```
<expression>[a-zA-Z&&[^BALANCE\\s\\d+$]]</expression>
```

Is there an alternative way to get the same output that the above expression would yield without the `&&` literals?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `CDATA` blocks:

```
<expression><![CDATA[YOUR_PATTERN]]></expression>
            ^^^^^^^^^            ^^^
```

Inside them, you can store the pattern as a literal string, no need to escape or entitize anything.

Note that `[a-zA-Z&&[^BALANCE\\s\\d+$]]` is not doing what you might think: it matches any ASCII letters `a-zA-Z` with the exception of `B`, `A`, `L`, `N`, `C`, `E`, `\`, `s`, `d`, `+` and `$`. You will need to edit it according to the pattern specifications.

**EDIT**: To write `]]>` in a CDATA block, use `<![CDATA[]]]]><![CDATA[>]]>`, i.e. add up 2 CDATA blocks, one up to and including `]]` and another one for `>`. It is advised to use some XML parser to actually create these CDATA blocks.

Comment: One reservation: the content of the CDATA block cannot contain the sequence `]]>`. Which is not as unlikely a sequence as might appear when you are holding stuff like regular expressions.